# Piping two inputs into comm

Tags: linux, pipe

I have two lists I produce using the following commands:

1. ```
   find . -type f -name config.php -exec ls {} \;
   ```
2. ```
   find . -type f -name config.php -exec grep --files-with-matches some_string {} \; | sort
   ```

How could I pipe the lists into `com -23` so I can see those entries from list1 that aren't contained in list2?

Comment: You didn't specify your shell. If the linked question is not helpful (e.g. if you're using a shell with no support for process substitution) then please [edit] the question, state your shell and the fact you can't use process substitution. We will reopen the question then.

Comment: Few things about your specific approach: (1) Are you sure you need `-exec ls {} \;`? I expect `-print` (or nothing at all) to generate basically the same output. (2) How about `grep --files-without-match` in the first place? Piping to `comm` may be unnecessary (compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)).

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the solution. My shells was bash so it is appropriate and it worked.

Comment: Yes, the -exec ls {} \; was unnecessary... I removed it. The --files-without-match would not have given the same result, but thank you for the suggestions.